# Dragonboard can't detect RawGameController

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot, dragonboard

I am making a UWP app that runs on an Arrow Dragonboard. The Dragonboard is running Windows IoT (10.0.17763.1)

I've plugged a USB joystick into the Dragonboard, but Windows doesn't seem to detect it.

```
var rawInputController = Windows.Gaming.Input.RawGameController.RawGameControllers.FirstOrDefault();
//rawInputController is null
```

If I run my app on my local machine, and plug the same joystick into my PC, the joystick IS detected.

Is there something that I need to configure on the Dragonboard in order for this to work?

Comment: Hi Dave, can you see your joystick appears in the connected devices list on Windows IoT Core DefaultApp? We can see from [Hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist) that Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller is compatible with Windows 10 IoT Core. What's kind of your joystick?

Comment: Hi Rita, sorry for the delay.

My joystick shows up in Connected Devices as "USB Mulitimedia Keyboard". I am using this joystick that I purchased from Amazon. It's a DIY kit, but it's supposed to function as a standard USB joystick.

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B06XC7PPQQ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Hi Dave, you can check from your PC device manager when you plug the joystick that which driver files (device properties->driver->driver details) the device use. Then to see if you can find all these file on Windows IoT Core device. BTW, the device shows as "USB Mulitimedia Keyboard" on PC?

Comment: In Device Manager on my PC, the joystick is listed as "HID-compliant-game controller", and when I click on Driver Details, I get a message that says "No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device.". If I enumerate all devices on my PC by using `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()` the device name is "Generic USB Joystick".

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by modifying the package manifest of my UWP app. I added the following lines to the `<Cabailities>` node.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="usage:0004 *"/>
    <Function Type="usage:0005 *"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

This doesn't seem to be a requirement on PC, but it is required for the Dragonboard.

Comment: Hi Dave, glad to hear you get it to work. Thanks for sharing.